# Diferença entre recv e read, send e write

Tags: c, c++, socket

Estou transmitindo e recolhendo dados a partir de uma conexão utilizando *Sockets*, para enviar os dados para o servidos, pode-se usar os comandos `send` e `write`, e para receber os dados `recv` e `read`.

- Existe diferença nesses comandos?
- Qual a vantagem/desvantagem pode ter em usar `send` ou `write` para enviar algum dado?
- Qual a vantagem/desvantagem pode ter em usar `recv` ou `read` para receber algum dado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Send**

Tanto clientes como servidores utilizam a função *send* para transmitir dados. Tipicamente, um cliente envia uma requisição e o servidor envia uma resposta.

**Recv**

Tanto clientes como servidores utilizam a função *recv* para obter dados que foram enviados pelo outro.

**Read e Write**

Em alguns sistemas operacionais, como o Linux, as funções *read* e *write* podem ser utilizadas em vez de *recv* e *send*.

**Vantagem do Read e Write**
A grande vantagem de utilizar *read* e *write* é a generalização - uma aplicação pode ser criada com o objetivo de transferir dados para ou a a partir de um descritor sem saber se o mesmo corresponde a um arquivo ou um *socket*. Dessa forma, um programador pode utlizar um arquivo no disco local para testar um cliente ou um servidor antes de tentar se comunicar através da rede.

**Desvantagem  do Read e Write**
O programa perde a portabilidade quando é compilado em outro sistema operacional.

*Fonte 01* : Rede de computadores e Internet - 6 ed. Douglas E. Comer
*Fonte 02* : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1790775/2588695

Comment: Ainda o uso de read/write em substituição a send/recv implica na não utilização das flags permitidas pelas funções send e recv (é equivalente a passar 0 no lugar deste parâmetro nas funções que o possuem).

Comment: esqueci de colocar essa parte srsrsrs